# Can I use LaTex in WhatsApp?

Tags: mathjax, markdown, rendering

I've tried [this](http://www.math.ucla.edu/~robjohn/math/mathjax.html), but it didn't work.

Also tried using Markdown, although it only works when you're writing a message (not once you've sent it).

Comment: Are you talking about the Whatsapp Web or the mobile app?

Comment: Even if MathJaX would work, I think this is off-topic

Comment: You can't for now and probably won't ever.

Comment: It would be Whatsapp Web. Sorry @ChristianHupfer - I saw someone else ask a similar question on this site about using LaTex in emails so I thought it would be appropriate.

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt: Yes, I know that for example Mozilla Thunderbird has add-ons with LaTeX display, but I think, that's MathJaX still in the background.

Comment: For what is worth, you can use LaTeX in Telegram with [@LatexBot](https://telegram.me/latexbot).

Answer (score 7):

Whatsapp Web doesn't render mathjax. Even if some browser plugin renders it for you, the user at the receiving end would also need it. And if the receiver is using mobile app, it is not going to work.